# Inheritance instead of typedef

Tags: c++, inheritance, templates, typedef

C++ is unable to make a template out of a typedef or typedef a templated class.  I know if I inherit and make my class a template, it will work.

Examples:

```
// Illegal
template <class T>
typedef MyVectorType vector<T>;

//Valid, but advantageous?
template <class T>
class MyVectorType : public vector<T> { };
```

Is doing this advantageous so that I can "fake" a typedef or are there better ways to do this?

Comment: similar question, same answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/293988/generic-vector-of-vectors-in-c

Comment: Your second example is invalid too. You will have to write your own constructors for MyVectorType since you can not inherit them.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

C++0x will add template typedefs using the `using` keyword.

Your solution declares a new type, not a type "alias", e.g. you cannot initialize a `MyVectorType &` (reference) with a `vector<T>`. This might not be a problem for you, but if it is, but you don't want to reference vector in your code, you can do:

```
template <typename T>
class MyVectorType {
public:
  typedef std::vector<T> type;
};
```

Comment: std::vector has a non-virtual destructor so you need to be careful not delete a MyVectorType via a std::vector*

Comment: I was not proposing to use MyVectorType as the actual datatype, but rather MyVectorType<T>::type, which is a typedef for std::vector<T>, so no danger here.

Answer (score 10):

Inheritance is not what you want. A more idiomatic approach to emulating a templated typedef is this:

```
template <typename T> struct MyVectorType {
    typedef std::vector<T> t;
};
```

Refer to the typedef like this:

```
MyVectorType<T>::t;
```

Answer (score 1):

> C++ is unable to make a template out of a typedef or typedef a templated class.

That depends on what you mean by `typedef`:  `std::vector<size_t>` is legal -- even though `size_t` is a typedef -- and `std::string` is a `typedef` for `std::basic_string<char>`.

Answer (score 1):

What you should use depends on how it should behave (overload resolution for example):

- If you want it to be a new distinct type

  ```
  class Foo : public Whatever {};
  ```

  However, you can now pass pointers or references of `Foo`, to functions accepting `Whatever`, so this becomes a hybrid. So in this case, use `private` inheritance, and `using Whatever::Foo` or custom implementations, to expose the methods you want.
- If you want a type synonym

  ```
  using Foo = Whatever;
  ```

The former has the advantage that it is possible to predeclare a class, but not a typedef.