# C++ 2D dynamic array crash

Tags: c++, dynamic, multidimensional-array

Hi I'm having some problem with 2D dynamic array.

```
int main()
{
   double **M;
   int M_dimension;
   int i;

   M_dimension = 10;

   M = new double *[M_dimension];
   for (i=0;i<M_dimension;i++)
   {
      M[i] = new double[M_dimension];
   }

   M[0][0] = 1.0;

...
}
```

Program works but I'd like to initialize 2D array using such a function:

```
void initialize2D(double **M,int M_dimension)
{
   int i;
   M = new double *[M_dimension];
   for (i=0;i<M_dimension;i++)
   {
      M[i] = new double[M_dimension];
   }
}
```

Finally the program looks like this:

```
int main()
{
   double **M;
   int M_dimension;
   int i;

   M_dimension = 10;

   initialize2D(M,M_dimension);        

   M[0][0] = 1.0; //crash

...
}
```

Unfortunately it crashes at `M[0][0] = 1.0;`

Thanks for any help or suggestions.

Comment: If this isn't for practice I recommend you to use a vector of vectors. It's much easier to handle.

Comment: A vector of vectors has its own set of problems. You don't usually want a jagged array, and vector of vectors don't have as good locality as a single contiguous 2d array

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are passing `M` by value, instead of by reference. `initialize2D` needs to change the value of the pointer-to-pointer `M` such that it points to the memory allocated

Try changing your function signature to this instead:

```
void initialize2D(double **&M,int M_dimension)
```

Or

```
void initialize2D(double ***M,int M_dimension) {
    ...
    *M = new double *[M_dimension];
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a reference to `double**` instead of `double**` to function, otherwise the modification done to a pointer after assigning M the reslut of `new` get lost on exit from a function.

Answer (score 0):

what the problem might be is where you declaring an integer parameter such as int M_dimension
void initialize2D(double **M,int M_dimension)

and then you initializing the dynamic array as:
M[i] = new double[M_dimension];

where it comes to contradiction because you declared the variable M_dimension as an integer and then you using it as a double

try it this way:
either change the data type of array or the M_dimension, so then both of them have the same data type.

hopefully this will help you out

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `std::vector` or [Boost.MultiArray](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/multi_array)

It would be quite easy exercise to define 2-dimension array as [generic vector of vectors in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/293988/generic-vector-of-vectors-in-c/2211411#2211411)