# Modify malloc strategy for 2D Array so malloc succeeds

Tags: c++, c, malloc

We recently received a report that our application will occasionally fail to run. I tracked down the problem code to this:

```
struct ARRAY2D
{
   long[] col;
}

int numRows = 800000;
int numCols = 300;
array = (ARRAY2D*) malloc(numRows * numCols * sizeof(long))
```

This allocation of 800 Mb can fail if the user doesn't have a large enough free block. What is the best way to change how I allocate the memory?

Keep in mind that I have a large amount of code that accesses this object like this: array[row].col[colNum], so I need something that requires *minor or primarily find & replace* editing of the array access code.

Comment: Are you using C or C++? Your tags aren't helping.

Comment: @Poita: he's probably using C++ but only the C features. *shrug*

Comment: Is it always the case that your app needs to allocate this memory or is it dependant on a particular scenario in the app?

Comment: I always have to allocate this much memory.

Comment: Does C++ let you declare arrays like `long[] a` instead of `long a[]`?  I have seen that type of syntax in questions tagged C or C++ way too many times.  Or are people just not copying and pasting their code?

Comment: Something of this size is begging for a memory mapped file...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can allocate smaller chunks of memory separately, instead of one huge block.

```
long** array = NULL;  
array = (long**) malloc(numCols * sizeof(long*));  
for (int i = 0; i < numCols; i++)  
   array[i] = (long*)  malloc(numRows * sizeof(long));
```

Generally, [memory allocation may fail](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malloc#Allocation_failure), every allocation. However, let's say statistically, due to [memory fragmentation](http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/14060), allocating a single large block of memory has higher chance to fail more often than allocating N number of smaller blocks.
Although, also the solution above may cause problems as it is a bit like a double-bladed sword because it may lead to further memory fragmentation.

In other words, there is no generally perfect answer and solution depends on details of a system and application.

As from the comments it seems C++ library is a possibility, then solution based on  `std::vector` (i.e. [generic vector of vectors in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/293988/generic-vector-of-vectors-in-c/2211411#2211411)) or using [Boost.MultiArray](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/multi_array)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your code snippet. The allocation can still fail, right?

Answer (score 7):

Will there be a lot of default values in your `ARRAY2D`? If yes, you need a sparse array. The *minimal change* would be to use an `unordered_map` (or `hash_map` or `map`):

```
static const int numRows = 800000;
static const int numCols = 300;

struct ARRAY2D {
  long col[numCols];
  // initialize a column to zero; not necessary.
  ARRAY2D() { memset(col, 0, sizeof(col)); }
};


// no need to malloc
std::unordered_map<int, ARRAY2D> array;
...
// accessing is same as before ...
array[1204].col[212] = 4423;
printf("%d", array[1204].col[115]);
...
// no need to free.
```

If the row indices are always continuous but much less than `numRows`, use a `std::vector` instead.

```
std::vector<ARRAY2D> array;
...
// resize to the approach value.
array.resize(2000);
...
// accessing is same as before ...
array[1204].col[212] = 4423;
printf("%d", array[1204].col[115]);
...
// no need to free.
```

Comment: There will be default values in certain parts of the array. Sometimes there were be less rows than numRows and less columns than numCols.

Comment: OP has tagged with C and C++, so I'd assume he is looking for solution usable in C as well

Comment: @Brian: Having less rows and columns than the maximum is fine because an unordered map will use more memory only when the number of entries increases.

Comment: @Andreas Bonini presumably to indicate he is using C features only, elements of C standard library.

Comment: @mloskot: I find this unlikely

Comment: @mloskot: Even if OP restricts to C there is still lots of hash table libraries for C.

Comment: If STL is the best choice, then I can use it.

Comment: @Andreas Bonini I'm curious, just a guess or have read it from the question itself? I don't have access to my magic crystal ball, so I can only read words that are written. It says: C and C++ (see tags)

Comment: If I'd use an unordered map for the columns, should I also use it for the rows?

Comment: @Brian: Sorry. How will you access the 2D array again? `array.col[colNum]` is syntax error. Do you mean `array[rowNum].col[colNum]`?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a simple example, how i would allocate the array in large chunks:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct ARRAY2D {
  long *col;
  char free;
};

struct ARRAY2D *ARRAY2D_malloc( int numRows, int numCols ){
  struct ARRAY2D *rows = malloc( numRows * sizeof(struct ARRAY2D) );
  if( rows ){
    for( int i=0,b=numRows; i<numRows; i+=b ){
      char *mem;
      while( b && !(mem = malloc(b*numCols*sizeof(rows[0].col[0]))) ) b--;
      if( b<1 ){
        while( --i >= 0 ) if(rows[i].free) free(rows[i].col);
        free(rows); rows=NULL; break;
      }
      for( int j=i; j<i+b && j<numRows; j++ ){
        rows[j].free=(j==i);
        rows[j].col = (void*)mem; mem += numCols*sizeof(rows[0].col[0]);
      }
    }
  }
  return rows;
}

int main(void){
  int numRows = 8000000;
  int numCols = 300;
  struct ARRAY2D *array = ARRAY2D_malloc( numRows, numCols );
  if( array ){
    printf( "array[numRows-1].col[numCols-1]=%li\n", array[numRows-1].col[numCols-1]=3 );
  }
  else{
    puts("not enough memory");
  }
}
```

`b` is the number of rows allocated in one step. Decrementing `b` with one is a simple strategy when there are no large blocks of free memory.

Answer (score -2):

Your code has syntax errors: you are missing a semicolon and `long[] col;` is invalid C or C++.

Given:

```
struct ARRAY2D
{
   long *col;
};
ARRAY2D *array;
int numRows = 800000;
int numCols = 300;
array = (ARRAY2D*) malloc(numRows * numCols * sizeof(long));
```

you are potentially allocating the wrong amount of memory: `sizeof(long)` should be replaced by `sizeof *array`, or `sizeof(ARRAY2D)`.

Assuming you got the right amount, you can index your `array` as: `array[i]`, for `i` in the range `[0, numRows*numCols)`.  You haven't allocated any memory for `col` members of any of the `array[i]`, so you can't index into `col` of any of those.  Your use of `array[row].col[colNum]` is therefore wrong given the allocation scheme you have posted.

Perhaps it would help if you posted some real code that works.