# C malloc with 2D Array: Why there isn't a segmentation fault?

Tags: c, malloc

I use this method for doing malloc over a 2d array, my sources are
http://c-faq.com/aryptr/dynmuldimary.html and [Modify malloc strategy for 2D Array so malloc succeeds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213342/modify-malloc-strategy-for-2d-array-so-malloc-succeeds):

```
int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    long **array = NULL;

    array = malloc(5 * sizeof(long *));
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        array[i] = malloc(3 * sizeof(long));

    array[4][2] = 515;
    array[4][3] = 212;
    array[4][10000] = 3;

    printf("%ld\n", array[4][10000]);

    return 0;
}
```

My question is,
Why don't I get a segmentation fault in the execution of any of the last three lines before the return? Is it safe (ignoring the inexistence of free)?

Comment: c doesnt check array boundaries, it usually depends on the OS to ensure that you are accessing valid memory

Comment: If you're doing C (and not C++), many people recommend omitting casting `void *` pointers to other types. In particular, I would change `array = (long **)malloc(5 * sizeof(long *));` to `array = malloc(5 * sizeof *array);` which, if you change the type of `array`, will still produce the correct size for `malloc`. (I'd make the other call `array[i] = malloc(3 * sizeof **array);` as well.)

Comment: So, it's "safe" as long as I don't try to access beyond my own boundaries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The operating system allocates memory to an application in pages (typically 4 KB). For efficiency, it is possible to use Huge Pages (e.g. 2 MB)

The first page 0 is never allocated and if you ever try to access it you get a segmentation fault. e.g. accessing any pointer from 0 - 4095 will get a segmentation fault on most systems.

However, once a page has been allocated to you, you can read and write any part of that page without a segmentation fault. (Code pages are usually protected from writes)

When you use malloc it makes sure that the pages you need are there.  However you could just access the memory you have and change any way you like. (Assuming you knew how much that was)

Generally, this is more dangerous than useful, but it may help explain why accessing memory in an invalid way doesn't guarantee a segmentation fault.

Note: malloc has a small structure e.g. 8 bytes, at the start of each allocated block of memory before the block itself, if you corrupt this then `malloc` and `free` will not work correctly.

Answer (score 6):

You're invoking undefined behaviour. Undefined behaviour, as its name implies, isn't defined to cause a segmentation fault. That code could set the value of that memory to the value you're giving it, it could ignore the assignment completely, or it could order pizza for all we know.

Answer (score 1):

`malloc` is only part of how memory is allocated to a process.

Memory is given to a process by the operating system in whole pages, so 4kB or 4MB (or other...) size chunks -- large. The process, in userspace, then has the freedom to chop up those pages how it likes.

`malloc` serves 2 roles:

- request pages from the OS
- partitioning those pages into allocated chunks

So I bet what's happening is you're landing somewhere else in a page you own, just not in a chunk you've allocated. As far as tho OS is concerned it's OK.

Answer (score 0):

Writing to memory that you don't own doesn't necessarily cause segmentation faults.

It's when you overwrite other pointers, then later try to access those pointers that is causing the segmentation faults. That's why these errors are typically difficult to debug.

Answer (score 0):

This is the classic heap corruption bug. It may or not not crash--depends on how lucky you are.

You are overwriting parts of the heap that are most likely not being used or are corrupting it in such a way as to not be fatal.