# c++ map that contains any type of data, including vectors, maps etc; NO BOOST

Tags: c++, dictionary

I need a map that supports mappings from any type to any type.

As the title says, any type means (among others) vectors, maps, all types of numbers etc.

I consider writing some kind of wrapper, as I found out here (http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/heterogeneous-list.html) that maps need to contain heterogeneous types (actually arrays need that, but maps ar associative arrays).

Any thoughts on that, or what my approach on this should be?

Thanks

Comment: You could have a struct with a type enum and a void* entry for the data

Comment: I'm assuming order isn't a factor, since with utterly disjoint types, there is none. My thoughts on your approach are fairly simple: If you think this is a solution, you better be sure you understand the problem, and I don't mean the problem with your solution.

Comment: Copy the relevant parts of [Boost.Any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/any.html). Or use [`QVariant`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtcore/qvariant.html).

Comment: Do you mean that you need to store different types in the same map? You'll need something like [Boost.Any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/any.html) for that; either change your "NO BOOST" requirement, or rewrite it yourself.

Comment: You can think of this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/293988/generic-vector-of-vectors-in-c

Comment: It's not possible. You say "from any type". But some types do not have a strict weak order, which means you can't use them as keys in a map. No matter how you wrap them up or invent ways to order the types themselves, if you can't order the values within the type then you can't have a map. Or for unordered maps, same argument with hash instead of order.

Comment: Use Qt, and QVariant!

Comment: Well ok, maybe I have exagerated when I said "from any type", but I certanly need to map TO any type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cannot use boost, you could write your own "variant" type.

That would contain:

- Some value (string or numeric) that is shows what type it holds.
- Somewhere to store the data. This can either be a union, or a generic data blob which is then interpreted by the interpreter associated with your type.

Given that you want to be able to use this for the keys as well as the values of your map, you must have `operator<` defined on your variant type, or some other strict ordering predicate that you can use for your map.

Note that your map will be able to contain any type you like, as long as you provide a key for your type, and converters between that type and the opaque data structure that your map actually stores. You would also need to register your type on some kind of table.

With `boost::variant`, all the types you may use are "registered". With `boost::any`, types are not registered but when extracting, you need to know what type you are expecting to find. Neither of these can be used in keys to maps, but they can be used in values.

The boost-any model does not use any kind of variable to denote the type. Instead you have a model something like this (probably better implemented)

```
class AbstractBase
{
public:
  virtual ~AbstractBase() {}
};

template< typename T >
struct AnyImpl : public AbstractBase
{
   T t;
};

typedef shared_ptr< AbstractBase > AbstractBasePtr;

class Any
{
   AbstractBasePtr ptr;

 public:
   bool cast( T & t ) const
   {
      shared_ptr<AnyImpl<T>> tptr = pointer_cast< AnyImpl<T> >( ptr );
      if( tptr )
      {
         t = tptr->t;
         return true;
      }
      else
         return false;
   }
};
```

Ok, so I created a base class from which you derive a holder to any type, then you can store shared pointers to this because they are heterogenous, and then you can try casting them to the type you want it to have.

A useful learning exercise maybe. Practically, likely to be badly-implemented compared to boost.

A holder of "derived" does not hold a type of "base" and if you want pointers, you are now wrapping pointers in pointers which isn't great. Your types have to be copyable and assignable. However it is likely to work.

Comment: As I said in a comment above, I have exagerated with the "from any key", but the "to any value" part is still valid. Thank you for your answer, I was actually considering this now

Comment: For a "to any value" you no longer need to implement operator< or any kind of strict ordering for your variant type. If you don't want to use boost, the options of how to implement it essentially are union or opaque data type with something somewhere to indicate the type, boost-any actually uses dynamic-cast for this. I will explain in a moment.

Comment: Really similar to what I thought of in the mean time. I will test this and let you know how it worked.

Answer (score 0):

One of the way for `"mappings from any type to any type"`, is to implement specialization for `any types` regarding requirements of std::map. e.g. comparison for a keys or copy-constructor for values for a classes like:

```
temaplate <typename T>
class MapKey {  };

temaplate <typename T>
class MapValue {  };
```

and define your map like:

```
template <typename TKey, typename TValue>
class Map : public std::map< MapKey<TKey>, MapValue<TValue> > 
{ /* map methods */ };
```

To use `std::vector<int>` as a key in `Map` you need to implement specialization `MapKey<std::vector<int>>`